# Как сделать условное форматирование для одной колонки?

Tags: excel

Есть прайс, который я забираю через `Power Query` из `Mysql`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В нем одна колонка - это наши цены, а все остальное - цены конкурентов. Я хочу сделать форматирование зеленым цветом на цене конкурента - если оно меньше чем у меня, и наоборот - красным. Сделал как на скрине - но никак не работает. Нет выделения цветом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем в выделение, к которому применяется форматирование, включены заголовки?

Comment: @Akina проверил и без заголовков - аналогично

Comment: Для начала - неправильная формула. Она сравнивает только В2 и С2. Убери доллары перед 2 и С.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc5ha.png

Answer (score 1):

Выделить столбцы с ценами конкуретов (`C:F`). Записать правила форматирования. Так создадутся общие форматы для этих столбцов. Так удобнее - не нужно отслеживать диапазон с данными; при удалении/добавлении строк УФ не дробится на несколько одинаковых форматов.

Формула УФ для цен, которые больше исходных:

```
=ЕСЛИ(СТРОКА($B1)>1;C1>$B1)
```

Чтобы не закрашивались пустые ячейки, в формулу для меньших цен можно добавить проверку на наличие цены:

```
=ЕСЛИ(СТРОКА($B1)>1;ЕСЛИ(C1;C1<$B1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример макроса, который выполняет условие:

```
Sub Макрос1()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 100

If Cells(i, 2) > Cells(i, 1) Then
With Workbooks("Книга1.xlsm").Sheets("Лист1").Cells(i, 2).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13551615
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
End If
If Cells(i, 2) < Cells(i, 1) Then
With Workbooks("Книга1.xlsm").Sheets("Лист1").Cells(i, 2).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13561798
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
End If

If Cells(i, 3) > Cells(i, 1) Then
With Workbooks("Книга1.xlsm").Sheets("Лист1").Cells(i, 3).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13551615
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
End If
If Cells(i, 3) < Cells(i, 1) Then
With Workbooks("Книга1.xlsm").Sheets("Лист1").Cells(i, 3).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13561798
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
End If

If Cells(i, 4) > Cells(i, 1) Then
With Workbooks("Книга1.xlsm").Sheets("Лист1").Cells(i, 4).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13551615
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
End If
If Cells(i, 4) < Cells(i, 1) Then
With Workbooks("Книга1.xlsm").Sheets("Лист1").Cells(i, 4).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13561798
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
End If

If Cells(i, 5) > Cells(i, 1) Then
With Workbooks("Книга1.xlsm").Sheets("Лист1").Cells(i, 5).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13551615
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
End If
If Cells(i, 5) < Cells(i, 1) Then
With Workbooks("Книга1.xlsm").Sheets("Лист1").Cells(i, 5).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13561798
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
End If

If Cells(i, 6) > Cells(i, 1) Then
With Workbooks("Книга1.xlsm").Sheets("Лист1").Cells(i, 6).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13551615
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
End If
If Cells(i, 6) < Cells(i, 1) Then
With Workbooks("Книга1.xlsm").Sheets("Лист1").Cells(i, 6).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13561798
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

*если строк больше 100, то измените значение в цикле For*

Comment: Макрорекодер - хорошо, но он должен быть вспомогательным инструментом, а не создателем "*макрсов, решающих задачу*" С таким подходом, как записал автомат,  можно подвесить книгу. === УФ для диапазона - всего одно условие.Вы же задаете УФ для **каждой отдельной ячейки**. Т.е. если ячеек 500 - 1000 условий в УФ.  Зачем?! Да и можно упереться в ограничения по количеству форматов.  === Работа с объектами листа медленная, у Вас выделяется каждая ячейка. Учитесь работать без *Select'ов*.

Comment: подредактировал свой макрос. убрал лишние select'ы. теперь работает без зависаний.